# Spotlight always 1 Search Behind

Tags: spotlight, search

Have the strangest issue on my computer.  Let's say I go to Spotlight and search "ABC" -- it displays the results from the search I made previous.  So now if I reopen Spotlight and search "XYZ", it will display the results for "ABC" -- this is consistent and happens every time, even after rebooting.

I've tried the reindexing of Spotlight instructions.  No change.

If I search in Finder, I get the proper results for all searches.

Any ideas?

Running iMac Pro with MacOS Ventura.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend deleting the Spotlight Cache:

Enter the following command in Terminal: `sudo mdutil -E /`

Press <kbd>⏎ Return</kbd>.

You'll be prompted for your password. Enter it and press <kbd>⏎ Return</kbd> again.

This command will erase the Spotlight index for your main drive. Spotlight will then start reindexing, which might take some time.